How can I paginate between pages and still keep the URL parameters with Nextjs?
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Card, CardContent } from "../ui/card";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight, Ellipsis } from "lucide- 
react";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

type Props = {
  currentPage: number;
  count: number;
  perPage: number;
};

const Pagination = async ({ currentPage, count, perPage }: Props) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / perPage);
  const pages = [];
  const offset = 1;
  for (let i = currentPage - offset; i <= currentPage + offset; i++) {
    if (i >= 1 && i <= totalPages) {
      pages.push(i);
    }
  }
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(undefined);
    });
  });
  if (totalPages === 1) return null;
  return (
    <div className="px-[2.5%]">
      <Card className=" w-fit rounded-xl mx-auto">
        <CardContent className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2 p-2 ">
          {currentPage > 1 ? (
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/components",
                query: {
                  page: currentPage - 1,
                },
              }}
            >
              <Button variant="ghost" className="w-10 h-10">
                <ChevronLeft className="w-5 h-5 shrink-0" />
              </Button>
            </Link>
          ) : null}
          {typeof count === "number" && (
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
              {pages.map((page, idx) => {
                return (
                  <Link
                    key={idx}
                    href={{
                      pathname: "/components",
                      query: {
                        page,
                      },
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button
                      variant="outline"
                      className={cn(
                        "w-10 h-10 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg",
                        page === currentPage
                          ? "bg-accent border-accent"
                          : "bg-transparent"
                      )}
                      size="sm"
                    >
                      {page}
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )}
          {currentPage < Math.ceil(count / perPage) ? (
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
              <Button
                variant="ghost"
                className="w-10 h-10 hover:bg-transparent cursor-default"
              >
                <Ellipsis className="w-5 h-5 shrink-0" />
              </Button>
              <Link
                href={{
                  query: {
                    page: currentPage + 1,
                  },
                }}
              >
                <Button variant="ghost" className="w-10 h-10">
                  <ChevronRight className="w-5 h-5 shrink-0" />
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

 export default Pagination;

The app I am building has filters and a search, but whenever I go to a different page, if I have a search or an active filter, those parameters are erased from the URL and all I have is the "?page=#ofPage". I want to find a way to keep the URL parameter when I change pages with my pagination for a better user experience. Or if that is not possible, can I do it using query-string? If so how? I appreciate any help you can provide.
Update: I have added a few lines by adding the constants pathname, searchParams, and params, so now I can add ${pathname}?${params.toString()} to my Link pathname, but now the problem is that I get the current page and the page I want to go to in my URL, so, if I can remove the current page from the URL with .set, I think it can work.
I ended up doing it with query strings.
"use client";
import qs from "query-string";
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Card, CardContent } from "../ui/card";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight, Ellipsis } from "lucide- 
react";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

type Props = {
  currentPage: number;
  count: number;
  perPage: number;
};

export const Pagination = ({ currentPage, count, perPage }: 
Props) 
=> {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const selectedValue = searchParams.get("page");
  const onClick = (slug: number | undefined) => {
    const currentPath = qs.parse(searchParams.toString());
    const query = {
      ...currentPath,
      page: slug,
    };

    const url = qs.stringifyUrl({
        url: window.location.href,
        query,
     },
      { skipNull: true }
    );
    router.push(url);
  };

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / perPage);
  const pages = [];
  const offset = 1;
  for (let i = currentPage - offset; i <= currentPage + offset; 
i++) {
    if (i >= 1 && i <= totalPages) {
      pages.push(i);
    }
  }
  if (totalPages === 1) return null;
  return (
    <div className="px-[2.5%]">
      <Card className=" w-fit rounded-xl mx-auto">
        <CardContent className="flex items-center justify-center 
gap-2 p-2 ">
          {currentPage > 1 ? (
            <Button
              variant="ghost"
              className="w-10 h-10"
              onClick={() => onClick(currentPage - 1)}
            >
              <ChevronLeft className="w-5 h-5 shrink-0" />
            </Button>
          ) : null}
          {typeof count === "number" && (
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
              {pages.map((page, idx) => {
                return (
                  <Button
                    key={idx}
                    variant="outline"
                    className={cn(
                      "w-10 h-10 flex items-center justify- 
center 
rounded-lg",
                      page.toString() === currentPage.toString()
                        ? "bg-accent border-accent"
                        : "bg-transparent"
                    )}
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={() => onClick(page)}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </Button>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )}
          {currentPage < Math.ceil(count / perPage) ? (
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
              <Button
                variant="ghost"
                className="w-10 h-10 hover:bg-transparent 
cursor- 
default"
              >
                <Ellipsis className="w-5 h-5 shrink-0" />
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="ghost"
                className="w-10 h-10"
                onClick={() => onClick(currentPage + 1)}
              >
                <ChevronRight className="w-5 h-5 shrink-0" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};


An approach could be preserving the current query string, and then append them again on the props of the next link, something like this:
const Pagination = async ({ currentPage, count, perPage }: Props) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
  const router = useRouter(); // remember to import useRouter
  const initialQuery = router.query; // save the initial query strings
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / perPage);
  const pages = [];
  const offset = 1;
  for (let i = currentPage - offset; i <= currentPage + offset; i++) {
    if (i >= 1 && i <= totalPages) {
      pages.push(i);
    }
  }
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(undefined);
    });
  });
  if (totalPages === 1) return null;
  return (
    <div className="px-[2.5%]">
      <Card className=" w-fit rounded-xl mx-auto">
        <CardContent className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2 p-2 ">
          {currentPage > 1 ? (
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/components",
                query: {
                  ...initialQuery, // pass the initial query to next route
                  page: currentPage - 1,
                },
              }}
            >
          // rest of your code
            


I ended up doing it with query strings. I added the code to the question.

Did you try this approach?, why did you decide to use an external library for something that you can do with nextjs itself?

I tried, but I have to mount the next router

And the docs are not very clear about it.
